# Convert IEEE754 format response to double value in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus, rs485

How to convert float return in IEEE754 format to readable value?

The response return from device is `02 03 04 43 5D 38 10 5F 69` where:

02 - Slave Address
03 - Function Code
04 - Byte Count
43 5D 38 10 - Value return from device
5F 69 - CRC

Below are the code that I use:

```
void ModbusHandler()
{
    try
    {
        while (run)
        {
            byte[] resp = new byte[9];
            while (!modread.TheReadingFunction(startaddr, datalength, devid, fn, ref resp)) ;
            if (resp != null)
            {
                if (!dataevents.IsDisposed)
                    UpdateTextBox( PrintBytes(resp));
                string myFloat = floatConversion(resp).ToString();
                if (!dataevents.IsDisposed)
                    UpdateTextBox($"Conversion: {myFloat}");

                double val0 = ToFloat(resp);
                if (!dataevents.IsDisposed)
                    UpdateTextBox($"Value 0: {val0}");

                double val1 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(resp[3] << 8 | resp[4] & 0xFF), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                if (!dataevents.IsDisposed)
                    UpdateTextBox($"Value 1: {val1}");

                double val2 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(resp[5] << 8 | resp[6] & 0xFF), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                if (!dataevents.IsDisposed)
                    UpdateTextBox($"Value 2: {val2}");

                double res1 = (resp[3] << 8 | resp[4] & 0xFF);
                double res2 = (resp[5] << 8 | resp[6] & 0xFF);
                if (!dataevents.IsDisposed)
                    UpdateTextBox($"Byte 1: {res1}|Byte 2: {res2}");
            }
            else
            {
                if (!dataevents.IsDisposed)
                    UpdateTextBox("Reponse is null");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        if (!dataevents.IsDisposed)
            UpdateTextBox($"Error in modbus read: {err.Message.ToString()}");
    }
}
float floatConversion(byte[] data)
{
    float result = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? data.Reverse().ToArray() : data, 0);
    return result;
}
float ToFloat(byte[] input)
{
    byte[] newArray = new[] { input[2], input[3], input[0], input[1] };
    return BitConverter.ToSingle(newArray, 0);
}
```

And below are the result on screen:-

```
16:31:58.905 PM - {02 03 04 43 5B 21 06 35 36}
16:31:58.907 PM - Conversion: 4.547139E-19
16:31:58.908 PM - Value 0: 3.8280496566377E-37
16:31:58.909 PM - Value 1: 17243
16:31:58.909 PM - Value 2: 8454
16:31:58.909 PM - Byte 1: 17243|Byte 2: 8454
```

The value on device currently is ~ **207.686V** its a power meter

Comment: Are you sure that the response is telling you the voltage in IEEE754? Because 207.686 would be `9E AF 4F 43`,you can see it by yourself: `Single sing = 207.686f;  var iee = BitConverter.GetBytes(sing);          Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(iee));`

Comment: If the real result is 221V, then `var arr1 = new byte[] { 0x43, 0x5D, 0x38, 0x10 }; Array.Reverse(arr1); var flt = BitConverter.ToSingle(arr1, 0);` gives it.

Comment: So you could: `Array.Reverse(resp, 3, 4); float volts = BitConverter.ToSingle(resp, 3);` and your IEEE754 was in big endian format.

Answer (score 2):

If you result was in truth 221.219V then:

```
Array.Reverse(resp, 3, 4); 
float volts = BitConverter.ToSingle(resp, 3)
```

your IEEE754 number was in big endian (while your computer is little endian), so you reverse the bytes and convert them.

Comment: I think you are right,but have a look at OP code. This `float result = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? data.Reverse().ToArray() : data, 0);` does the same and should give the right result....Althoug i've notice that he is doing it for all the response, not the real data :)

Comment: @Pikoh And reversing the whole response changes the start index of the various fields... It would have been better to reverse the single "pieces" of information that need reversing.

Comment: Yes.The process should be first split the response into the different parts, and after that reversing them and `BitConverter.ToSingle`. That should work just fine

Comment: @xanatos, your comment on main post was right.. I was taking all byte into the BitConverter. Which I suppose to take byte[3] - byte [6] only. The response sending all byte including, start, datalen, crc so my mistake was converting all. You comment was right